# OSMNX KeyError: 'x' when trying to get_nearest_nodes()

Tags: python, geopandas, osmnx

I currently have a process where I

1. Download Open Street data using ox.geocode_to_gdf()
2. Get the Geopackage edges and nodes using and use gpd.overlay() to edit the edges and nodes based on another map
3. Convert edited edges back to OSMNX as a graph using ox.graph_from_gdfs()

At this stage, I have a graph (sample [here](http://www.filedropper.com/gpost200curcentre))
where I would like to use to estimate the shortest path among some points. I have the Easting and Northing of these points and I am trying to get he nearest nodes to these cooridnates using

```
nodes_flood = ox.distance.get_nearest_nodes(g_post_200_Cur_centre, Easting, Northing)
```

so that I can run nx.shortest_path() with the graph and destination nodes. But I get an error message

```
File "<ipython-input-74-ed9774662a83>", line 1, in <module>
nodes_flood = ox.distance.get_nearest_nodes(g_post_200_Cur_centre, Easting, Northing)

File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/Kinshasa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py", line 256, in get_nearest_nodes
nn = [get_nearest_node(G, (y, x), method="haversine") for x, y in zip(X, Y)]

File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/Kinshasa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
nn = [get_nearest_node(G, (y, x), method="haversine") for x, y in zip(X, Y)]

File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/Kinshasa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py", line 138, in get_nearest_node
df = pd.DataFrame(coords, columns=["node", "x", "y"]).set_index("node")

File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/Kinshasa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 563, in __init__
data = list(data)
File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/Kinshasa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py", line 137, in <genexpr>
coords = ((n, d["x"], d["y"]) for n, d in G.nodes(data=True))

KeyError: 'x'
```

Not sure what is causing this. I have OSMNX v1.0.

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal, reproducible code snippet that allows us to fully reproduce your problem from scratch. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by passing the method argument to the get_nearest_nodes(). If you chose the 'kdtree' as the method, you will not have the error.

```
nodes_flood = ox.distance.get_nearest_nodes(g_post_200_Cur_centre, Easting, Northing, method='kdtree')
```

However, I still don't know the reason for the error if I was not passing the method name.